# How to fit census tracts within Voronoi Polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, census, voronoi-thiessen

I have a map with Voronoi polygons and I need to join census data  in it. The problem is that the geometry of voronois and census tracts (CT) do not match.

My goal is is to place census tracts (or only part of them, in most cases) within the corresponding voronois.

I'm having trouble thinking about how to calculate or weight the census data, since the census tracts might be contained in more than one voronoi polygon at the same time. Say, for example, how can I calculate the average population for any area of influence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot of your data would help but I would build a [Modelbuilder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm) model:

1. [Make Feature Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm) on Census tracts with Use Ratio Policy on Population Field. This way the population will be split accourding to intersections with the voronois in the next step
2. [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) Census tracts with Voronoi
3. [Summary Statistics](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) with sum of population as statistics and voronoi id (or whatever) as case field

[image]

Comment: Alright, directions were very helpful indeed. Thanks.